# Cygwin, bash, change an environmental variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cygwin

I have set up a Cygwin environment on my machine (Windows 8.1).

pol@pol-lap1 ~/Downloads/software/database/firebird/Firebird-2.5.4.26856-0

```
$ `set | grep unknown`
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="3" [2]="33" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-unknown-cygwin")
                echo "bash: $FUNCNAME(): \`${!OPTIND}': unknown argument" 1>&2;
                194,10xCelsius 194,unknown 198,offlinescanuncsectorct \
```

However, when I do `env | grep -i unknown`, nothing is returned.

```
pol@pol-lap1 ~/Downloads/software/database/firebird/Firebird-2.5.4.26856-0
$ env | grep -i unknown

pol@pol-lap1 ~/Downloads/software/database/firebird/Firebird-2.5.4.26856-0
```

Notice, the environmental variable's value is 4

```
pol@pol-lap1 ~/Downloads/software/database/firebird
$ echo $BASH_VERSINFO
4
```

Now, what I want to do is change the value of $BASH_VERSINFO[5] to x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu in order to "fool" the system into compiling a programme that I want.

I tried to `export BASH_VERSINFO[5]=x86_64-redhat-linux-info`, but that changed nothing.

Maybe I don't fully understand the difference between the `set` and the `env` commands in Linux. Why do I get a different value with set as with env?

I would be grateful if anyone could shed any light on these issue and let me know what I can do to change my variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 BASH_VERSINFO[5]=x86_64-redhat-linux-info
```

Output:

```
bash: BASH_VERSINFO: readonly variable
```

---

Btw. see: [Hacky method to unset readonly variable with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17397069/3776858)